# Kustomize resource GitHub private repository

Tags: github, kubernetes, devops, kustomize

I was wondering if is possible to get resources from [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) in a private GitHub repository, I already tried something like this without success

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1

kind: Kustomization

resources:
- git@github.com:gituser/kustomize.git/kustomize/main/nginx.yaml

- ssh://github.com/gituser/kustomize.git/kustomize/main/nginx.yaml
```

error

```
Error: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from 'ssh://github.com/diego1277/kustomize.git//kustomize/main/nginx.yaml': evalsymlink failure on '/Users/diego/Desktop/estudo/kustomize/see/base/ssh:/github.com/diego1277/kustomize.git/kustomize/main/nginx.yaml' : lstat /Users/diego/Desktop/estudo/kustomize/see/base/ssh:: no such file or directory': evalsymlink failure on '/private/var/folders/qq/mk6t7dpd5435qm78_zsfdjvm0000gp/T/kustomize-056937086/kustomize/main/nginx.yaml' : lstat /private/var/folders/qq/mk6t7dpd5435qm78_zsfdjvm0000gp/T/kustomize-056937086/kustomize: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your remote resource needs to resolve to a *directory* that contains a
`kustomization.yaml` file. That is, instead of:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- git@github.com:gituser/kustomize.git/kustomize/main/nginx.yaml
```

You need:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- git@github.com:gituser/kustomize.git/kustomize/main/
```

And your `kustomize/main` directory should contain
`kustomization.yaml`. You can try this out using a public repository,
for example:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - "git@github.com:kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/examples/helloWorld"
```

Comment: With the public repo example I had always a `Error: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from 'git@github.com:kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/examples/helloWorld': evalsymlink failure on ... hit 27s timeout running 'git submodule update --init --recursive'`. But after having added a `ref` attribute, it works well:
`- "git@github.com:kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/examples/helloWorld?ref=v1.0.6"`

Comment: The imposed limitation on having to be a directory instead of a file is senseless.